# PHP - какие есть паттерны или варианты реализации EventManager?

Tags: php

При реализации разных классов, часто нужно реализовать возможность, чтобы пользователи классов имели возможность изменить входные данные метода или результирующие.

Потел бы понять, какие есть принципы реализации, или паттерны?

Например:

```
class Foo {

    public function getDiscount($arFileds) {
       # событие, которое дает возможность из вне, модицифировать данные $arFileds

      # ... arRsult

      # событие, которое дает возможность из вне, модицифировать данные $arRsult
      return $arRsult;
    }

}
```

Какие есть методы решения задач? Что бы можно было одновременно несколько событий обработать?

Например что-то в этом роде (это пример как я представляю, может есть какие-то интересные паттрены, которые решают эту задачу?):

```
EventManage::getInstance()->on("beforeGetDiscount", function (&$arFileds) {
    # modify $arFields
    return $arFields;
});

EventManage::getInstance()->on("beforeGetDiscount", function (&$arFileds) {
    # modify 2 $arFields
    return $arFields;
});
```

И как вообще на практике ООП, нормальная ли практика, повесить несколько обработчиков на одно событие? Т.е. в одном месте мидифицировали входные данные, потом в другом?

Comment: Никто не знает?( или все отвечают только на вопросы, где можно быстро послать в гугл?

Comment: Просто расписывать с примерами долго. Можно отправить в фреймворки, где используется. Обычно обработчики делят на before-перед действием, on - при выполнении действия, after - после действия. Иногда вешается несколько обработчиков одного типа. Тогда надо указывать их приоритет. Symfony, Laravel, Битрикс. Везде используются свои системы событий